# Access PHP array element with a function?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a program that uses PHP's internal array pointers to iterate along a multidimensional array. I need to get an element from the current row, and I've been doing it like so:

```
$arr[key($arr)]['item']
```

However, I'd much prefer to use something like:

```
current($arr)['item'] // invalid syntax
```

I'm hoping there's a function out there that I've missed in my scan of the documentation that would enable me to access the element like so:

```
getvalue(current($arr), 'item')
```

or

```
current($arr)->getvalue('item')
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have already found the best solution: $arr[key($arr)]['item']

Comment: The `getvalue` approach would be useful even of single-dimmensional arrays too. It would allow to workaroung the ≤5.3 syntax limitations and allowing to access an element from an array, say returned by a function call, directly within one statement. I’m missing such internal function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I very much doubt there is such a function, but it's trivial to write

```
function getvalue($array, $key)
{
  return $array[$key];
}
```

Edit: As of PHP 5.4, you can index array elements directly from function expressions, `current($arr)['item']`.

Comment: I think this is probably what I'll end up doing. If you are correct that there is no such function, it's a pretty bad oversight.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using one of the [iterator classes](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php) yet? There might be something in there that does exactly what you want. If not, you can likely get what you want by extending the ArrayObject class.

Comment: Just looked at those - it looks like that's just an object oriented way to iterate through the array. The ArrayIterator::current returns the current item, much in the same way the current() function does, which isn't really the problem I was having.

Answer (score 0):

This function might be a bit lenghty but I use it all the time, specially in scenarious like:

```
if (array_key_exists('user', $_SESSION) === true)
{
    if (array_key_exists('level', $_SESSION['user']) === true)
    {
        $value = $_SESSION['user']['level'];
    }

    else
    {
        $value = 'DEFAULT VALUE IF NOT EXISTS';
    }
}

else
{
    $value = 'DEFAULT VALUE IF NOT EXISTS';
}
```

Turns to this:

```
Value($_SESSION, array('user', 'level'), 'DEFAULT VALUE IF NOT EXISTS');
```

Here is the function:

```
function Value($array, $key = 0, $default = false)
{
    if (is_array($array) === true)
    {
        if (is_array($key) === true)
        {
            foreach ($key as $value)
            {
                if (array_key_exists($value, $array) === true)
                {
                    $array = $array[$value];
                }

                else
                {
                    return $default;
                }
            }

            return $array;
        }

        else if (array_key_exists($key, $array) === true)
        {
            return $array[$key];
        }
    }

    return $default;
}
```

PS: You can also use unidimensional arrays, like this:

```
Value($_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD', 'DEFAULT VALUE IF NOT EXISTS');
```

Answer (score -1):

If this does not work, how is your multidimensional array composed? A var_dump() might help.

```
$subkey = 'B';
$arr = array(
    $subkey => array(
        'AB' => 'A1',
        'AC' => 'A2'
    )
);


echo current($arr[$subkey]);
next($arr[$subkey]);
echo current($arr[$subkey]);
```

Comment: The iteration I'm performing is really only along the primary array. I said "multidimensional" because the corresponding elements of the main array are themselves arrays, but I don't want to iterate over them - I just want to conveniently access them.

Comment: How about treating $arr[$subkey] as an array, or $new_arr = array_values($arr[$subkey])?

Footnote: what differs between your requested current($arr)['item'] and current($arr['item'])?

Answer (score -1):

I often use

```
foreach ($arr as $key=>$val) {
   $val['item'] /*$val is the value of the array*/
   $key         /*$key is the key used */
}
```

instead of

next($arr)/current($arr)

Comment: I use that too - for the sake of the question I eliminated the fact that I'm actually going down two sorted arrays looking for differences, and I' m pretty sure foreach doesn't support that kind of access, but I could be wrong. Anyways, thanks for your reply. :)