# php - find next row element value in array

Tags: php

I am returning an array of values using mysql_fetch_array.

In the while loop, i need to perform an if condition on the next element of the array.

E.g

```
if next($row) == 'test'
{
...
}
```

The thing is 'next($row)' is returning me the index of the next element in the array. I would like to test for the next $row("name").

```
if next($row("name")) == 'test'
    {
    ...
    } //this code is incorrect
```

Is there a way of doing this in php?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Duplicate question of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396519/access-php-array-element-with-a-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the "next($row)" gives you the index of the next cell in the array then just use it to perform the test. $arr[next($row)] = the next cell value/obj/whatever you have there

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($rows as $k => $row) {
    if (isset($rows[$k+1]) && $rows[$k+1] == 'test') //do something

    // Do normal stuff here
}
```